# Need to know try with resources for my function is correct or not

Tags: java, sonarqube, try-catch, try-with-resources

```
private Settings() {
    try {
        load(new FileInputStream("Settings"));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException | IOException  e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   
}
```

Above is my method. Please someone let me know below way is correct or not whe using try-with-resources

```
private Settings() {
    try(FileInputStream str = new FileInputStream("Settings")){
        load(str);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException | IOException  e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "correct way"? Is it not performaning as you expect? Does this help: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html

Comment: The first snippet is bad, as it does not manage the `FileInputStream` resource, it's been left open, the second snippet solves that issue

Comment: The second way will invoke the auto-close functionality of the try block https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html

Comment: @EwanBrown I mean the logic is correct or not?

Comment: The second block looks correct if you're asking about `try-with-resources` usage.  If you're looking for pointers, avoid naming a stream as `str`, that always reads as `String` to me.  Also, I'd flesh out that catch exception, `e.printStackTrace()` is never the right answer. :)